Does fontspec.sty [Scale=<n.m>] require grouping?
I needed the "fluid ounce" glyph from the Apple Symbols typeface. I thought it a bit too large, so scaled it using fontspec [Scale=0.9] The scaling seems to apply to all fonts when the use of the scaled font is not enclosed in braces. Is this expected? I searched the documentation and this site for information, but so far have found nothing that seems to speak to this. Using TeXLive 2024, up-to-date.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,fontspec}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ozsm}{}{{\appsym\char"2125}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ozsmng}{}{\appsym\char"2125}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsm}{}{{\appsym\char"211E}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsmng}{}{\appsym\char"211E}


%% |=====8><-----| %%

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
%% !!use of \appsym MUST BE IN A GROUP, or scale applies to ALL fonts: {\appsym...} ; \char"2125
\newfontface{\appsym}{Apple Symbols}[Scale=0.9]%
\newfontface{\recsym}{Coelacanth}[Scale=0.9]%

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
\ozsm\quad This is some text.

\ozsmng\quad This is also some text.

\ozsmng\quad This is some text. And, yet again, some more text.
\endgroup

\begingroup
\recsm\quad This is some text.

\recsmng\quad This is also some text.

\recsmng\quad This is some text. And, yet again, some more text.
\endgroup
\end{document}

Update
So that this might be more generally tested, I've included an example using a font available on CTAN (Coelacanth).


\appsym is a font switch like \bfseries or \sffamily. It applies until further notice or the end of the current group. If the symbol font doesn't contain characters for regular text, you might get a text font substituted after the symbol, but you might still get - so far as possible - the options requested for the current font. If the symbol font does support text, you get the symbol font with whatever options you've requested.
To see what's happening, let's define a new macro
\makeatletter
\newcommand\whichfont{\curr@fontshape}
\makeatother

\curr@fontshape returns the current LaTeX font as defined by the (not-so) New Font Selection Scheme. It has four parts separated by forward slashes:
<encoding>/<family>/<series>/<shape>

This is independent of engine, though the first element should typically always be TU on Unicode engines. \whichfont is just a convenience so we don't have to keep \makeatletter and \makeatothering.
Then we can test. We start with a baseline. (I also removed the STIX package as we don't really want anything additional playing with fonts.)
This is some text.
\whichfont

So we expect this to return Latin Modern.
Now our group.
\begingroup
\recsm\quad \whichfont This is some text.
\whichfont

\recsmng\quad \whichfont This is also some text.
\whichfont

\recsmng\quad\whichfont This is some text. And, yet again, some more text.
\whichfont
\endgroup

The result looks like this:

Coelacanth(o) is Coelacanth with a specific set of options.
This is exactly the way font switches always behave. \appsym is just like \sffamily or \bfseries or \itshape in this respect. So if you defined
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsmngbf}{}{\bfseries R}

you would not (hopefully) expect the results of \recsmngbf to be limited to the R. Rather, \recsmngbf would be defined to switch to the defined bold series, add an R to the typeset output and carry on. If you wanted to limit the bold to the R, you'd need on of the following:
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsmngbf}{}{{\bfseries R}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsmngbf}{}{\textbf{R}}

The application of \appsym is exactly parallel to the case of \bfseries.
Complete code:
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[debug]{tracefnt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsm}{}{{\appsym\char"211E}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsmng}{}{\appsym\char"211E}
\newfontface{\appsym}{Coelacanth}[Scale=0.9]%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\whichfont{\curr@fontshape}
\makeatother
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
This is some text.
\whichfont

\begingroup
\recsm\quad \whichfont This is some text.
\whichfont

\recsmng\quad \whichfont This is also some text.
\whichfont

\recsmng\quad\whichfont This is some text. And, yet again, some more text.
\whichfont
\endgroup
\end{document}


Note: I don't have Apple Symbol, so i could not test in the way egreg did. I could have kept STIX, but I think it is easier to see what is happening with as many defaults as possible.

I see nothing odd if I use the correct definitions.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,fontspec}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\newfontface{\appsym}{Apple Symbols}[Scale=0.9]
\newfontface{\recsym}{Coelacanth}[Scale=0.9]

\NewDocumentCommand{\ozsm}{}{{\appsym\symbol{"2125}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ozsmng}{}{{\appsym\symbol{"2125}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsm}{}{{\appsym\symbol{"211E}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recsmng}{}{{\appsym\symbol{"211E}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\ozsm\quad This is some text.

\ozsmng\quad This is also some text.

\ozsmng\quad This is some text. And, yet again, some more text.

\recsm\quad This is some text.

\recsmng\quad This is also some text.

\recsmng\quad This is some text. And, yet again, some more text.

\end{document}


When you used \ozsmng, you got
\appsym\char"2125\quad This is also some text.

so the text was typeset in Apple Symbols.

Ah. I feel foolish -- and a little blind as well. Thank you.
